# PHP : How to know if my query is success or not?

Tags: php, sql

I make this request :

```
$query_search = "insert into tbl_user (prenom, nom, ville, username, password) values ('".$prenom."', '".$nom."', '".$ville."', '".$username."', '".$password."') ";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
```

I would like to know if the result is success or not. How can i do this ?

Comment: Check the return value of the function perhaps?

Comment: Lots of downvotes.  Maybe explain to the user why?

Answer (score 1):

[`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) returns a resource, or `FALSE` on error. You can check for failure by checking what `mysql_query` returns, e.g.

```
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search);
if($query_exec === FALSE)
    ...error handling...
else
    ...success...
```

Currently, on error, you are telling PHP to give up and print out the error. This is because the `and` and `or` operators (rather than `&&` and `||` operators) have a *lower* precedence that assignment, hence `$query_exec` will contain the result of the comparison, and if it is `FALSE`, will cause PHP to die.

Note the use of `===`. This is a strict comparison, for which type coercion will not take place. While a standard `==` operator would be fine in this case (a resource won't be coerced to FALSE), it's good practise to use this operator when error checking. Many functions can succeed and return `FALSE`, instead returning `NULL` on error, which is coerced to `FALSE`. A strict comparison is required to differentiate between `FALSE` and `NULL` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please consider using the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) libraries as the `mysql_` prefix is deprecated and far less secure than the updated libraries.

Your new code would look like:

```
$sql = new MySQLi(//your database host, user, db name and password here);
$query_search = "insert into tbl_user (prenom, nom, ville, username, password) values ('".$prenom."', '".$nom."', '".$ville."', '".$username."', '".$password."') ";

$query_exec = $sql->query($query_search) or die($sql->error);
```

Additionally, if you are uncomfortable using Object Oriented syntax for PHP, you could use the procedural syntax for MySQLi like so:

```
$sql = new MySQLi(//database and connection information as before);
$query_search = "insert into tbl_user (prenom, nom, ville, username, password) values ('".$prenom."', '".$nom."', '".$ville."', '".$username."', '".$password."') ";

$query_exec = mysqli_query($sql, $query_search) or die(mysqli_error($sql));
```

It's important to note that with the new syntax for MySQLi you have to provide the procedural function with the `$sql` object as the `link` argument in the function

The `query` function returns `false` if the query fails and an object if it is successful, so you can test for a query result using:

```
if($query_exec) { 
    //do your success things 
} else {
    //error handling
}
```

As an extra note and something other users have mentioned, the `die` is not really necessary unless you absolute **have** to stop everything executing after the query fails. Normally, I would leave it at `$query_exec = $sql->query($query_search);` and do the fallbacks in the error handling part above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$query_search = "insert into tbl_user (prenom, nom, ville, username, password) values ('".$prenom."', '".$nom."', '".$ville."', '".$username."', '".$password."') ";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
if($query_exec)
{
echo "sucess";
}
else
{
echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: Won't this stop already by hitting the `die()` ? What are you checking then?

Comment: @Leri? How? a FALSE will trigger the die() call, and end the script right there. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ooh, so I did miss something :D

Comment: @DamienPirsy There was a _well hidden_ sarcasm. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `mysql_affected_rows()` to check how many rows were inserted or updated in a query.

So in your case:

```
$query_search = "insert into tbl_user (prenom, nom, ville, username, password) values ('".$prenom."', '".$nom."', '".$ville."', '".$username."', '".$password."') ";

$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

$affected_rows = mysql_affected_rows();

if($affected_rows > 0){
    //Rows inserted.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your $query_exec variable will be the judge of that, i.e will evaluate to true when it succeeded or false, if it failed. why did you even set it if you have to ask this?